# Preparred Statement error : ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, database, oracle, arraylist, prepared-statement

I have a little problem with my prepared statement. I got error ORA-00936: missing expression when doing `executeQuery()`. Can you tell me what i missed ?

In my class constructor.

```
private PreparedStatement reachOperation;
reachOperation = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM operations WHERE account_id = ? AND (date BETWEEN ? AND ?)");
```

My method.

```
  public List<Operation> getOperations(int number, Date from, Date to)
          throws DataStoreException {

            ArrayList <Operation> result = new ArrayList<Operation>();

        try {

            java.sql.Date debut = new java.sql.Date(from.getTime());
            java.sql.Date fin   = new java.sql.Date(to.getTime());


            reachOperation.setInt(1,number);
            reachOperation.setDate(2,debut);
            reachOperation.setDate(3,fin);


            ResultSet rs = reachOperation.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

            result.add(new Operation(rs.getInt(2),rs.getDouble(3),rs.getDate(4))); 

            }
            rs.close();
            return result;

        } catch (SQLException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            return result;
      }

  }
```

Call of method

```
    List<Operation>operations = new ArrayList<>();
              operations = manager.getOperations(1, minDate, maxDate);

// check just do prinln depending of the result of the boolean expression
              check("Blahblahblah", operations != null && operations.size() == 1);
              System.out.println("orders = " + operations);
```

Comment: where r u assinging value for number variable?

Comment: You mean the line reachOperation.setInt(1,number); or the call  operations = manager.getOperations(1, minDate, maxDate); ?

Comment: sorry its oracle use "date"

Comment: i didn't understand what you meant ^^'

Comment: date between ? And ? where date is a keyword to mention date datetype..so inorder to use it in query it should enclosed in " "

Comment: Ah, you were right, in the query, i use the wrong column name it's mydate and not date. No errors now. However, my list is empty while there should be stuff inside :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78567/discussion-between-sachu-and-csi).

Answer (score 4):

`date` is a reserved keyword in many RDBMS including Oracle, where you should escape it with double quotes `"` (*which should also be escaped with* `\` *in case string is created with double quotes*):

```
reachOperation = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM operations WHERE
                      account_id = ? AND (\"date\" BETWEEN ? AND ?)");
```

Comment: are you free ? You told me to ping back.

Comment: That's not it, i just had more questions and would like to know if we could open a chatbox ^^'

Comment: @Csi u can use above chat and comment me with @ symbol